# UNIX_TIMESTAMP with date in MySQL query not working

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

I have dates stored as a varchar in a MySQL database. I know this isn't ideal.. but it what's I have at the moment.

Example date:

```
$start_date = "11/22/2019";
$start_date = strtotime($start_date);
$end_date = "11/29/2020";
$end_date = strtotime($end_date);
```

I'm trying to write a query that checks to see if a date in this format falls within a range

I'm running into problems when the start date has the same month as the end date but a different year.

```
if (!empty($start_date)) {
    $where_clause[] = "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_date) >= '" . $start_date . "'";
}

if (!empty($end_date)) {
    $where_clause[] = "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_date) <= '" . $end_date . "'";
}
```

I read that UNIX_TIMESTAMP would allow me to do this but it doesn't seem to be working.

How can I make this query work?

Comment: I think the date should be formatted as `2019-11-22` *(yyyy-mm-dd)* then pass it as parameters of UNIX_TIMESTAMP. It doesn't accept any date format unless you convert it. https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-unix_timestamp-function.php

Comment: What exactly do the dates _in your database_ look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest thing to do here would be to just compare your MySQL text dates using `STR_TO_DATE` against proper ISO date literals in your PHP code.  That is, use a query along these lines:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%m/%d/%Y') > ?;
```

To the `?` placeholder you would bind a value such as `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('11/22/2019'))` and *not* `'11/22/2019'`, the latter which is in a non usable non-ISO format.

As you mentioned at the start of your question, it would be best to store all dates as bona fide date type column types, rather than text.